# Rails include Module in Concern Module and not lose instance object reference

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I have a concern module named `Translatable` where I'm trying to include a module called `AddressHelper`.

This is Translatable:

```
module Translatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include AddressHelpers

  def translated_primary_address_line
    address_helper_method
    ...
  end
end
```

And this is AddressHelpers:

```
module AddressHelpers
  def address_helper_method
    street = object.street_address
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem is, when included this way, `AddressHelpers` looses the reference to the instance object of the module that included `Translatable`.

Then this call:

```
object.street_address
```

Fails because object is nil.

How can I include AddressHelpers on my Translatable module and not lose the reference to the instance object?

Comment: Try making `AddressHelpers` a singleton and set the object within the singleton once, it will not lose reference. You could also use a `@@static` variable for the object, but again, you have to make sure that everything is wired up before you invoke

Comment: but AddressHelpers is a module. How can it be a singleton?

Comment: I was suggesting you could turn it into a singleton class since that isn't too far derived from what you originally intended it to do, sorry if I was unclear

Comment: thanks @David S. but I actually need to use the module methods simultaneously on multiple objects

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example, ie. the class that provides `object` and includes `Translatable`? I cannot reproduce your issue, but I made `AddressHelpers` an ActiveSupport::Concern, too.